# Driver issue with JDBC (SQL Server 18)

Tags: java, sql-server

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found
```

I've been having a lot of difficulty with the JDBC on SQL Server. My goal here is to unearth the exact cause of the issue/error at hand. I don't think it has anything to do with the driver itself; I added **mssql-jdbc-8.2.0jre13.jar** to the referenced library for this project as well as adding **jdk-13.0.1** under "installed JRE's" to ensure compatibility with the driver. Lastly, I added the line

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

but I'm still getting the same issue. Is it the URL itself that's causing the issue? I'm not sure if that's the right URL I should be using. The database that I'm currently trying to access is premade and has the server name

**occam-dbserver.cs.qc.cuny.edu\dbclass,21433**.

Must this be in the URL?
Must it be something like

**jdbc:sqlserver://occam-dbserver.cs.qc.cuny.edu:21433;Northwinds2019TSQLV5**.

```
package JBDC;

import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

    Connection myConn = null;
    Statement myStmt = null;
    ResultSet myRs = null;
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver:localhost:1433;Northwinds2019TSQLV5";
    String user = "student";
    String password = "abc";
    try {

        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

        myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user , password);

        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT *\r\n" + 
                "FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]");

        while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("EmployeeFirstName") + ", " + myRs.getString("EmployeeLastName"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (myRs != null) {
            myRs.close();
        }

        if (myStmt != null) {
            myStmt.close();
        }

        if (myConn != null) {
            myConn.close();
        }
    }
}

}
```

The specific error I'm getting is

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:localhost;Northwinds2019TSQLV5
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at JDBC.Driver.main(Driver.java:19)
```

Comment: what's the issue you got? could you add the exception and tell more what happens when you are trying to run this code

Comment: I edited in the error in my post. That's what I'm getting every time I try to run the class. I don't think it has to do with the driver itself. The driver (mssql-jdbc-8.2.0jre13.jar) was added to the referenced library and the JDK in "Installed JRE'S" is jdk-13.0.1. So it is probably the URL. What do you think the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

The .jar file is loaded on this line:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

So that's not your problem.  Compare your url

```
jdbc:sqlserver:localhost:1433;Northwinds2019TSQLV5
```

to the example from the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
 jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=<user>;password=<password>
```

So perhaps:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Northwinds2019TSQLV5";
```

Comment: Hello. I think this was successful in bypassing the previous error but now I'm getting this error

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Socket closed. Verify the connection properties....

Comment: Ensure that the SQL Server has TCP/IP enabled, and is listening  on port 1433, and there is no firewall blocking access.